# Jwplayer not pause/play by keyboard

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, jwplayer

I have integrated my jwplayer in my application but pressing space bar not pause/play video it scroll page to down. why? any workaround for that?

Comment: How are we suppose to help if you do not show us your code? Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You need to provide a link.

Comment: @EthanJWPlayer here you go for your sample site: http://jwplayer.electroteque.org/controls-markers/html5

Comment: I am asking for a link to your site. This isn't your site.

Comment: I know but even that keyboard feature is not working your demo site as well.

Answer (score 1):

> Due to a security feature, not all alphanumeric keys are available
>   when in fullscreen mode. These shortcuts will only work when outside
>   of fullscreen. Keyboard shortcuts are also not supported in Internet
>   Explorer 8.

Ref: http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1597259-keyboard-shortcuts

Also, JW Player 5 doesn't have keyboard control support, but I believe JW Player 6 does.